# Find out where a row ranks in a list of rows with different values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a ranking system for musicians, in my mysql table I have them listed like this:

```
id    genre    artist            rating      votes
1      rock    pink floyd         138         25
2      rock    black sabbath      149         28
3      pop     katy perry         98          12
4      rock    the who            72          14
```

Users may rate an artist on a scale of 1-10, on a vote I just increase the number (1-10) as rating to the table and increase the vote by 1, so to determine the rank I would divide the rating by votes and that would be the ranking.

I understand how to create an overview which displays all of the artists with the rank,I am however trying to find an efficient way to determine the ranking of a specific artist.

Long story short: If I was to be on the black sabbath sub page, how would I determine its ranking in the `rock` genre ?

I hope the explanation is understandable.

Comment: You appear to show Black Sabbath marginally ahead of Pink Floyd. This is obviously wrong! ;-) And don't get me started on Katy Perry...

Comment: @Strawberry Katy Perry is in the pop category so that doesn't count ;-). 
Unfortunately I'm not quite sure where to start, I'm not expecting ready written code here, just a point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   SELECT COUNT(mi.genre) + 1 rank
     FROM musician m
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT genre, ROUND(COALESCE(rating/votes,0),10) rating_per_vote
       FROM musician
          ) mi
       ON mi.genre = m.genre
      AND mi.rating_per_vote > ROUND(COALESCE(m.rating/m.votes,0),10)
    WHERE m.artist = 'black sabbath';
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23ec69/32)

**UPDATE**

You can actually drop the ids from the inner table, I did some playing around.
You do however need the `ROUND()` to make sure that the comparisons are correct.

Comment: I've tried the one with the ids, that works great ! Is there any significant advantage speed wise when using your updated solution which uses `ROUND()` instead ?

Comment: No idea, sorry, but as the comparisons were failing without the `ROUND()`.. I was worried about the case when two `rating_per_vote`s were the same (but different ids). Putting in the `ROUND()` caused the query to work as expected, adding the ids was just a work around. You could use both however (ids and `ROUND()`), but I'd benchmark it to see if it gave any benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, with less subqueries:

```
SELECT
    m.artist,
    r.rank,
    r.average
FROM
    musician m
JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            id,
            @rank := @rank + 1 rank,
            IF(votes = 0, 0, ROUND(rating/votes, 10)) average
        FROM
            musician, (SELECT @rank := 0) uv
        WHERE genre = 'rock'
        ORDER BY average DESC
    ) r
ON
    r.id = m.id
WHERE m.artist = 'black sabbath'
```